# How to override java jar application.properties from docker environment variables

Tags: java, docker, shell, maven, dockerfile

I have a maven java application with application.properties file in resources directory, and I have generated a .jar, and I want to override application.properties file inside .jar from docker environment variables.

application.properties:

```
url=myurl
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

COPY target/app.jar app.jar

COPY myentrypoint.sh /

CMD ["sh", "/myentrypoint.sh"]
```

myentrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# if the env var URL is not empty
if [ ! -z "${URL}" ]; then
   echo "url=${URL}" >> application.properties
fi

exec java -jar ./app.jar $@
```

and I want to override application.properties like this:

```
docker run -e URL='newurl' myimage
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to override the value you would use a single `>` to rewrite the file instead of appending to it (like with double `>>`).

[here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171025/what-does-do-vs) the difference

EDIT:
if you built the application.properties into the JAR file you can extract it change the value and build it again, a more appropriate solution would be to place the properties file in a common location like `/home/user/application.properties` and use this function `System.getProperty("user.home")`
or you could use the [Java Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)

[here's](https://crunchify.com/java-properties-files-how-to-update-config-properties-file-in-java/) another example.

thanks to [this](https://coderanch.com/t/616489/java/modify-Properties-file-JAR) thread.

Comment: this is not the issue, the question is how to access application.properties file inside .jar and then override it.

Comment: thanks for you replies, for the first suggesstion, I don't want to build the image every time I make a change, that would be a non apropriate way. And for the second suggestion that could be a solution, but the application.properties needs to be outside the project, which is not exactly what I'm looking for, I want to change application.properties which is inside the .jar with docker, I don't know if this is possible, hope it could be.

Comment: it could be if you'll add some mechanism that would "unzip" change and "zip" to a JAR file though I think its a bit too complicated relative to the second option of importing a new config in runtime from a mounted file